# libreria para conectar scanner de barras externo por bluetooth a app sin usar la camara

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth, scanner, código-de-barras

Alguno sabe de alguna librería para android studio para conectar un scanner de mano a una app y leer el contenido sin tener de hacer alguna clase de textbox donde le tenga que picar para que me lea lo que escanie
solo he visto para hacerlos por camara pero yo lo requiero por uno externo mediante bluetooth.

Gracias, excelente tarde

Answer (score 1):

Ya lo resolvi no es necesario usar libreria especial, solo hay que monitorear el bluetooth y leer lo que el escanner detecte, lo unico que hice fue poner el escaner en modo BT SPP Mode y puede detectar los textos que leía el escanner de barras sin tener que usar alguna clase de textbox

https://www.electroniclinic.com/how-to-create-android-app-for-arduino-sensor-monitoring-over-bluetooth/